Ubuntu 24.10 external monitors not detected after kernel update
In Ubuntu 24.10 after the kernel upgrade to 6.11 came via regular apt upgrade, my external monitors stopped working.
I use two workbenches, each has a docking station (one dell, one HP) with one or 2 standard monitors attached.
In both workbenches the monitors stopped working, they are not being detected anymore, i.e. they are not being shown as devices in the Gnome Settings dialogue.
I also tried with booting the kernel 6.12 (with my surface ubuntu version) but the same problem persisted.
I use a HP Envy x360 laptop for 1.5 years now - starting from ubuntu 22 via 23 to 24.10 all had no issue with the external monitors. So the issue clearly came with the kernel upgrade from kernel 6.11 onwards.
Any hint on how to go from here?
What to test / try / fix?
Is there a place where such kernel issues can be reported?
Thanks!
